# Burninate the code-cleanup tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The [code-cleanup](/questions/tagged/code-cleanup) tag isn't serving much of a purpose, and appears to be a meta tag. It definitely couldn't survive as the only tag on a question (as that question would be outrageously off-topic), hence this request.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Effectively, the tag is used in questions similar to the following ones:

- [Is there a dedicated Language Class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259927/is-there-a-dedicated-language-class-in-java) where the code cleanup is far to be implicit in the question
- [Remove unused source code files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155522/remove-unused-source-code-files), where knowing the user is trying to clean up the code is not relevant to answer the question
- [How to remove unused CSS but keep comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082736/how-to-remove-unused-css-but-keep-comments) which is also using [unused](/questions/tagged/unused)

If the tag were used for questions that were all off-topic, it could be kept for catching those off-topic questions; this is not the case, though, and the tag should be removed.